# Getting error that says: No such file or directory: 'mnist\\train-labels-idx1-ubyte'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am experimenting with some code samples from a book titled 'Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit Learn and Tensorflow' and I am getting an error that I don't understand: No such file or directory: 'mnist\train-labels-idx1-ubyte'

Just before I got this error I ran the code below.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
mnist

X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
X.shape

y.shape


import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
some_digit = X[36000]
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)
plt.imshow(some_digit_image, cmap = matplotlib.cm.binary,
interpolation="nearest")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]



from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)


sgd_clf.predict([some_digit])


y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)
y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)



from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)


sgd_clf.predict([some_digit])
```

Right after the last line of code, I see this message.

```
==================================================
Broadening the output spectrum using a hyperbolic tangent
--------------------------------------------------

Please make sure that you've downloaded and unzipped the MNIST dataset as described in the previous chapter. The following code assumes that you have created a mnist directory within this script's directory. Please hit 'enter' to continue.
```

After I hit the Enter key, I see this:

```
  File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 353, in load_mnist
    with open(labels_path, 'rb') as lbpath:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mnist\\train-labels-idx1-ubyte'
```

Any thoughts about what is going on here?  Thanks.

Comment: And this error is coming on which line? Maybe the downloaded data is corrupt. Try deleting the `'scikit_learn_data'` directory from your home folder and try again.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  I'll play around with it a bit more and move on soon if I can't get it working.  There is a lot left to get through in that book!